# How to prevent threads from reading inconsistent data from ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I'm using a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>` that works as a cache, and where read operations are performed to validate if an element is already in the cache and write operations to add an element to the cache.

So, my question is: what are the best practices to always **read the most recent ConcorrentHashMap values**?

I want to ensure data consistency and not have cases like:

1. With the `map.get("key")` method, the first thread validates that this key does not yet exist in the map, then it does the `map.put("value")`
2. The second thread reads the data before the first thread puts the element on the map, leading to inconsistent data.

Code example:

```
Optional<String> cacheValue = Optional.ofNullable(cachedMap.get("key"));

if (cacheValue.isPresent()) {
    // Perform actions

} else {
    cachedMap.putIfAbsent("key", "value");
    // Perform actions
}
```

How can I ensure that my `ConcurrentHashMap` is synchronized and doesn't retrieve inconsistent data?

Should I perform these map operations inside a synchronized block?

Comment: What does the Javadoc say that is unclear?

Comment: If you read the Javadoc you'll see that individual insertions and deletions occur atomically but the only guarantee for readers is that they won't see a partially completed change and thus there will be no `ConcurrentModificationException` thrown.

Comment: Yes @SolomonSlow! That what you said!

"that the second thread calls map.get("key") before the first thread calls put("key", data)"

Comment: Sorry, I deleted that comment, I think I misread your question.

Comment: @JimGarrison So, to ensure that the readings are always synchronized, what would you recommend?

Comment: Depends. _"...always read the most recent ConcurrentHashMap values"_ is too vague to answer.  Your requirements and logic dictate what this means.  "Most recent" for the entire map? For a given key? For a subset of keys? Something else?  Threads are hard because you have to consider a lot of stuff you can otherwise ignore in single-thread programming.

Comment: Yes! You are right!
In my case will be for the given key.

Comment: Do you know about the  [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)  method?

Comment: @TimMoore I didn't know about computeIfAbsent() but I've been exploring and it seems quite useful! And it seems ideal for my case, thanks for the suggestion.
However, I only have one con in my case. When isolating my logic to put in Function (2nd param of computeIfAbsent() ), my method throws an exception.
What would be the best practice in this case?

Comment: You would need to wrap it in a `RuntimeException`

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to do it this way:

```
if (cachedMap.putIfAbsent("key", "value") == null) {
    // Perform actions "IS NOT PRESENT" 
} else {
    // Perform actions "IS PRESENT"
}
```

Doing it in two checks is obviously not atomic, so if you're having problems with the wrong values getting put in the cache, then that's likely your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I understand your point of view. I hadn't thought of this way of building the if statement yet.
However, I can't apply it in my case, because the value I want to save is only calculated within this condition

Comment: You'll need to use methods like `computeIfAbsent` and the like, then.

Answer (score 0):

> what are the best practices to always read the most recent ConcurrentHashMap values?

Oracle's [Javadoc for `ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) says, "Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset." In other words, any time you call `map.get(...)` or any other method on the `map`, you are *always* working with the "most recent" content.

***BUT***

Is that enough? Maybe not. If your program threads expect any kind of consistency between two or more keys in the map, or if your threads expect any kind of consistency between something that is stored in the map and something that is stored elsewhere, then you are going to need to provide some *explicit* higher-level synchronization between the threads.

I can't provide an example that would be specific to the problem that's puzzling you because your question doesn't really say what that problem is.